# Example of DNS authoritative name server

Tags: dns

I have a question regarding the concept of "authoritative name server". I got an example from this topic which I'm not sure I totally understand it.
Example: Let says I want to start a new company called Network Utopia. I will register a name networkuptopia.com at DNS registrar. Then the registrar inserts two resource records into .com TLD server:

1. networkutopia.com IN NS dns1.networkutopia.com
2. dns1.netwworkutopia.com IN A 212.212.212.1.

Does this example means that I can request the real IP address of the server, which run my company's website, from authoritative name server, whose IP is 212.212.212.1?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, because a recursive DNS Resolver would contact the `.com`-Server to resolve `networkutopia.com` and would recieve `dns1.networkutopia.com` as the authoritative name server. To resolve `dns1.networkutopia.com` the resolver first needs to know the DNS Server for `dns1.networkutopia.com`. This is impossible (recursive dependency).

What you are looking for are so called "GLUE"-Records. These records allow you to host your authoritative DNS Server on the same domain.

Comment: Isn't that the authoritative DNS server just to provide the IP address of the actual server that running the website? Or the authoritative DNS server itself can run a website?

Comment: The authoritative DNS server is responsible for resolving all requests regarding a domain. You can have many records per Domain, not only A or AAAA records but also TXT, SRV, ... . These are retrieved and managed by the authoritative DNS Server of the domain in question.

The machine for the website and for your DNS server could be the same, just running two disjunct pieces of software (i.e. Web + DNS Server)

Comment: Ohh. So that the machine can serve as an DNS server to response any request I send to it, such as A record etc. At the same time, serves as a web server. Am I right?